# gulp: command not found after reinstalling node

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I recently had some issues with node which is why I reinstalled it multiple times. Now most things are working fine, however I am unable to use gulp in any projects since then.

I have been looking for solutions and tried removing gulp and reinstalling it globally with `npm install gulp-cli -g`, I added `scripts: {"gulp":"gulp"}` into my package.json as suggested in some places, ...

However, the problem remains. Whenever I try running any gulp command I get the error: `-bash: gulp: command not found`

Is it possible that it has something to do with the directory where the global gulp install is saved? When I run npm root -g I get `/Users/username/.npm-global/lib/node_modules`

This seems to be quite a common issue but I was unable to find a satisfying solution so far.

Comment: Gulp should be installed locally as well.  https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start

Comment: I know - I have been using it in numerous projects before and even though I haven't changed any files, it still returns the error. I just followed all the steps from that link and have the same result.